# Data with new line read as is in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a list of data for example Personal Information.  Now one of the field has this value

```
 xHistory = "160 \n 180 \n 190"
```

Now when I display the data, the whole text is shown as is!!!

How to make the Kendo grid read "\n" as a new line character.

```
 dataSource: {
      data: myData,
      pageable: false
 },
 columns: [{
     field: "xHistory",
     title "History",
     width: 90
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript function to render a column using column's template property in that function you can easily replace `"\n"` characters with a `"<br>"` tag.

```
columns: [{
    field: "xHistory",
    title "History",
    width: 90,
    template: renderHistoryCol
}]

function renderHistoryCol(model) {
    var text = model.xHistory;
    text = text.replace(new RegExp("\n", 'g'), "<br>");
    return text;

}
```

Here is the demo

```js
$(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    "columns": [{
      "field": "id",
      "title": "ID"
    }, {
      "title": "Name",
      "field": "name"
    }, {
      "title": "History",
      "field": "xHistory",
      "template": renderHistoryCol
    }],
    "dataSource": {
      "data": {
        "total": 5,
        "data": [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "john Deo",
          "xHistory": "160 \n 180 \n 190"
        }, {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "john Deo",
          "xHistory": "180 \n 300 \n 355"
        }, {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "john Deo",
          "xHistory": "355 \n 555 \n 190"
        }, {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "john Deo",
          "xHistory": "35 \n 445 \n 123"
        }, {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "john Deo",
          "xHistory": "160 \n 180 \n 343"
        }]
      },
      "pageSize": 5,
      "schema": {
        "data": "data",
        "model": {
          "fields": [{
            "field": "id",
            "type": "number"
          }, {
            "field": "name",
            "type": "string"
          }, {
            "field": "xHistory",
            "type": "string"
          }]
        },
        "total": "total"
      }
    },
    "height": 550,
    "sortable": true
  });
});

function renderHistoryCol(model) {
  var text = model.xHistory;
  text = text.replace(new RegExp("\n", 'g'), "<br>");
  return text;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```